# Golang program hangs without finishing execution

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have the following golang program;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://yahoo.com/",
}

type HttpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
    status   string
}

func asyncHttpGets(url string, ch chan *HttpResponse) {
    client := http.Client{}
    if url == "http://www.google.com/" {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //google is down
    }

    fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    u := &HttpResponse{url, resp, err, "fetched"}
    ch <- u
    fmt.Println("sent to chan")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("start")
    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse, len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        go asyncHttpGets(url, ch)
    }

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Im done")

}
```

<kbd>[Run it on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TfzA_SQn5e)</kbd>

However when I run it; it hangs (ie the last part that ought to print `Im done` doesnt run.)
Here's the terminal output;;
$ go run get.go
start
Fetching http://yahoo.com/
Fetching http://golang.org/
Fetching http://www.google.com/
sent to chan
&{http://www.google.com/ 0xc820144120  fetched}
sent to chan
&{http://golang.org/ 0xc82008b710  fetched}
sent to chan
&{http://yahoo.com/ 0xc82008b7a0  fetched}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that ranging over a channel in a for loop will continue forever unless the channel is closed. If you want to read precisely `len(urls)` values from the channel, you should loop that many times:

```
for i := 0; i < len(urls); i++ {
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good dirty devious trick would be to use `sync.WaitGroup` and increment it per `goroutine` and then monitor it with a `Wait` and after its done it will close your channel allowing the next blocks of code to run, the reason I am offering you this approach is because it gets away from using a static number in a loop like `len(urls)` so that you can have a dynamic slice that might change and what not.

The reason `Wait` and `close` are in their own goroutine is so that your code can reach the `for loop` to `range` over your channel

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://yahoo.com/",
}

type HttpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
    status   string
}

func asyncHttpGets(url string, ch chan *HttpResponse, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    client := http.Client{}
    if url == "http://www.google.com/" {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //google is down
    }

    fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    u := &HttpResponse{url, resp, err, "fetched"}
    ch <- u
    fmt.Println("sent to chan")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("start")
    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse, len(urls))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go asyncHttpGets(url, ch, &wg)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Im done")

}
```